Geometry Nodes, turn a mesh into a 3d-printed object
I'm trying to render objects, as if they were 3d-printed.
A shader with lines are not realistic enough.
I've been trying to solve this with geometry nodes. One thing i tried is using a raycast node to wrap a spiral around an object. 
This kind of worked, except when the object is floating above the origin, there will be a random point in the origin, making the spiral go through that point (thats not on the mesh)

Also the top wont be covered by this setup.
Another way i hoped it was possible is by taking sections of the object and using that path to map a solid to.
How would you suggest picking this up?
Thanks
Edit:
This would be what im hoping to reach.


Could you describe in more detail what you want the final result to look like? Sharing an image of your semi-working GN setup is good, but I'd like to see or read a detailed description of what your ideal solution looks like.

Ive edited the post for more clarification :)

So, you said "the top won't be covered by this setup", but the target images you've shared also don't have tops. What do you expect it to look like if there's a plane of geometry parallel to the ground plane? What should it do if the mesh splits into multiple separate islands (like a person with raised arms)?
